# Expected argument of type "integer", "App\Entity\Material" given

Tags: symfony, doctrine

first of all I must say i'm very new to Symfony so sorry if I'm asking some kind of silly question.

I have a controller that builds a form with some EntityType fields in it that display  dropdowns in the template, and I also have the basic code for handling form submissions.

My problem is when this form gets submitted looks like in some part of the code (like *$form->handleRequest($request)* or *$entity = $form->getData()*) crashes processing the *$form* object with the posted request values, and in the error it says it's because on first EntityType field processed it's expecting integer type instead of the Entity object class.

I can't see where is the issue in my code, all I can say is I'm expecting the  dropdowns with integer type values in  to be posted as integers and not as Entity objects :/

Also excuse my bad english, hope you understood everything decently. Thanks for reading.

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use App\Entity\Lot;
use App\Entity\Material;
use App\Entity\Provider;
use App\Entity\Responsable;

class CompraController extends Controller
{
/*
 * @Route("/buy_lot", name="buy")
 * @Method({"GET","POST"})
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $lot = new Lot();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($lot, array('allow_extra_fields' => true))
        ->add('IDmaterial', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Material::class,
            'required' => true,
            'choice_value' => function ($material) {
                return $material ? $material->getIDmaterial() : '';
            },
            'choice_label' => function ($material1) {
                return $material ? $material->getNameMaterial() : '';
            }
        ))
        ->add('N_Lot', TextType::class, array(
            'required' => true,
        ))
        ->add('Quantity', IntegerType::class, array('required' => true))
        ->add('Price', NumberType::class, array(
            'required' => true,
            'scale' => 2,
        ))
        ->add('IDprovider', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Provider::class,
            'required' => true,
            'choice_value' => function ($provider) {
                return $provider ? $provider->getIDprovider() : '';
            },
            'choice_label' => function ($provider) {
                return $provider ? $provider->getNameProvider() : '';
            }
        ))
        ->add('IDresponsable', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Responsable::class,
            'required' => true,
            'choice_value' => function ($responsable) {
                return $responsable ? $responsable->getIDresponsable() : '';
            },
            'choice_label' => function ($responsable) {
                return $responsable ? $responsable->getNameResponsable() : '';
            }
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Buy'))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $lot = $form->getData();
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($lot);
            $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('buy');
    }

    return $this->render('stock_app/buy.html.twig', [ 
       'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

And my Lot Entity (the one is supposed to be flushed) vars look like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $IDlot;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $N_Lot;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $Quantity;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", scale=2, nullable=true)
 */
private $Price;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Provider", mappedBy="IDprovider", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $IDprovider;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Responsable", mappedBy="IDresponsable", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $IDresponsable;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Material", mappedBy="IDmaterial", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $IDmaterial;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your doctrine annotation from:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Material", mappedBy="IDmaterial", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $IDmaterial;
```

to:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Material", mappedBy="IDmaterial", cascade={"persist"})     
 */
private $material;
```

You don't need to specify columns types on your relation properties, so omit them on all your relation definitions

Comment: ok, thanks Jeroen! found some more mistakes on my code while I was adapting your solution and now it's finnally working :D

Comment: You are welcome ! Do you want to accept the answer or is it not sufficient ?

Comment: already did it but im new in the platform so it doesn't show up til i have 15 points on reputation